# display gif when mousemoveon and hide it when mousemoveout

Tags: javascript

I have two gif images, when first clicked, it should display playgif.gif image. playgif image has a map to make the menue clickable.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="Object170" onmouseout='hidemenue(this)'>
            <img src="assets/images/playagif.gif" alt="" usemap="#planetmap">
            <map name="planetmap">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,168,49" href="about.htm" alt="about">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,57,168,106" href="basics.htm" alt="basics">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,117,168,176" href="advanced.htm" alt="advanced">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,180,168,230" href="fags.htm" alt="fags">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,239,168,288" href="x.htm" alt="x">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,301,168,349" href="contact.htm" alt="contact">
            </map>
        </div>
        <div class="Object181">
            <img src="assets/images/aboutagif.gif" onmouseover='showmenue(this)' width="100px" height="200px">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showmenue(x) {
    x.style.display = 'none';
    var playgif = document.getElementsByClassName("Object170");
    playgif[0].style.display = 'block';
    console.log("hide about and display animation");

}
function hidemenue(y) {
    y.style.display = 'none';
    var playgif = document.getElementsByClassName("Object181 > img");
    playgif[0].style.display = 'inline-block';
    console.log("hide animation and display about");

}
```

here is the [source code](http://jsfiddle.net/wasim/v6j0yr2c/)

**When I hover over playgif.gif image, it disappears again**! Please tell where is the problem in my code!?

Comment: Your fiddle has errors.

Comment: @P5Coder that's why I am posting a question here

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("Object181 > img");` won't work.

Comment: @Moob oh, right.. jQuery inside!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function showmenue(x) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("Object181")[0].style.display = 'none';
    var playgif = document.getElementsByClassName("Object170");
    playgif[0].style.display = 'block';
}
function hidemenue(y) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("Object170")[0].style.display = 'none';
    var playgif = document.getElementsByClassName("Object181");
    playgif[0].style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v6j0yr2c/2/

Comment: @dotfreelancer Sorry I had put wrong link. Please check this one.

Comment: it works, but when mouse go out of map areas, it fire mouseoverout event!